# Control macOS touchbar media keys

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

Using the `CGEventTap` way, I am able to intercept the media keys (F7 - F9) in my application and prevent stuff like iTunes from opening. However, is there a way to change the icon that's displayed? For example, when playing a youtube video in safari or music in iTunes, the button will change from 'play' to 'pause' as appropriate, but in my case it remains as the generic 'play/pause' button.

There's clearly an API to do this, but I haven't found it yet.

EDIT: for clarification, I'm not talking about the "App Controls" touchbar that any application can show; rather I'm talking about the touchbar that is shown when "Expanded Control Strip" is selected in system preferences -- the one that is global across all apps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution, it is `MPRemoteCommandCenter`. First, you must setup the handlers:

```swift
let remote = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
remote.playCommand.isEnabled = true
remote.playCommand.addTarget { (MPRemoteCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in 
    // ...
}
```

Note that from my experience you *might* need to setup handlers for `playCommand`, `pauseCommand`, `togglePlayPauseCommand`, `nextTrackCommand`, and `previousTrackCommand` in order for this to work.

Then, to actually change the button state, use `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().playbackState`, which can be `.playing` or `.paused` or whatever.

However, in my case since I was already hooking the media buttons through another mechanism, the handlers I setup above do nothing; they just need to be there apparently so the OS knows about your app. Setting the `playbackState` still works.